# python tkinter rectangle resize

Tags: python, tkinter

how can i resize my rectangle(canvas_bar) ?
am making hp bar to follow the object(monster)
and need to resize by it hp

```
hp = 100
hp_x = 100/5    
canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x+20, self.y+hp_x, 
fill='red')

self.canvas.move(self.canvas_bar, self.vx, self.vy)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdyHP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `coords` method to change the coordinates of an object.

The following example gets the current coordinates for the item identified by `self.canvas_bar`, and then makes the bar 100px wider:

```
(x0, y0, x1, y1) = self.canvas.coords(self.canvas_bar)
self.canvas.coords(self.canvas_bar, (x0, y0, x1+100, y1))
```